# Is it possible to create an array of html snippets with Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I have a HTML-snippet which I would like to repeat with Angular.js.

Let's say I have a row with 10 blocks in it (10 divs).
I have created a HTML snippet of such a block.

I would like to have this block repeated 10 times in this row, using the snippet I made.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you can use the `ng-repeat` directive. For instance,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in toRepeat">
<!-- some HTML here --->
</div>
```

where `$scope.toRepeat` contains 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

Directive :

```
this.getTimes=function(n) {
    var a = new Array();
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            a.push(i);
            }
        return a;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block1"ng-repeat="n in blockCtrl2.getTimes(24)"></div>
```